# QGIS connect to database Filemaker

Tags: mysql, database, odbc, filemaker, qgis

I want to connect Filemaker DB with QGIS. Now I have already created some basic tables in QGIS.

Say I want to display detail information for each county in the United States. Now I got the countyID both in QGIS and Filemaker tables, I want to use countyID as foreign keys to link tables so that we could enable QGIS to display all the data from database.

Now I only have countyID in QGIS and the database stores all the detail information of each county (Population, Area, County Name...etc).

I am not sure if there is an interface to connect QGIS with Filemaker; If not, should I create a new database in MySQL and connect MySQL with QGIS? How?

Comment: I am using Filemaker Pro-14, QGIS 2.8.2. In Mac platform

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the data from FileMaker you can use FileMaker ODBC driver. The Server version also support XML publishing.

MYSQL sounds like a good approach. You can use MYSQL tables directly in FileMaker using ESS.

Comment: I tried to use ODBC to connect with QGIS directly. The connection is successful but QGIS software just cannot recognize tables in FileMaker..

Comment: Check the link above. The syntax of FileMaker SQL is a bit different and you need to setup and query your DSN correctly. This is the most probable cause you do not see the tables.